# Norwegian keyboard / Writing in english

Tags: keyboard, language

I have my keyboard Language set to Norwegian (3 extra letters of the alphabet). When writing in English the first letter of the words (not all - but lots) change to a capitol letter - why??  Many may say - well just change the keyboard to English when writing English, but then I would have to re-learn where all the keys are (e.g: @ ? ' ( ) =  and so on)

Comment: In what application are you writing? Are you using some sort of spellcheck?

Comment: Does it affect some specific words or does it happen randomly?

Comment: This happens when writing on facebook or email for example. Spellcheck is on (i.e. most of these Words I'm writing now are getting underlined in red - as they are not recognised in Norwegian). When I'm writing a sentence - one or two of the Words (often 'your' and 'you') will suddenly switch the first letter of some Words to a Capitol (it's just done it now - With 'words')

Comment: I'll ask now what browser are you using, what addons, etc. From what you've described, it most likely seems like an addon trying to capitalize letters, although the random nature of it is unusual.

Comment: I use IE, have Java and Adobe, nothing unusual

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to buy a USB English keyboard and have both Norwegian and English connected at the same time and just switch keyboards when needed

Comment: Having two keyboards just to type in two languages is definitely not a simplest solution.

Comment: Find it easy to change keyboard Language. The Choice is on the taskbar at the bottom of the screen. It's not simple at all switching keyboard Language regarding writing - as all of the non-alphabet keys are in completely different Places.